# Display the details of the specific file which I select in the list

Tags: python, qt

My list has 'n' number of files in it.
When I select a particular file in the list, the details of that particular file should be displayed in another textbox.

[image]

Above picture is the tool which I have developed .
Left hand side panel ('Input') shows the list of items present.
When I click any one of the file in the list, the details of it should be populated in the right-hand side panel ('Overall Output')

How to do that ???

Comment: Before starting to write code, you should read a primer on human interface guidelines etc.

Comment: You need to connect selection changing signal of your "input" list to a slot where you have to process the selected items information and display it in the right side window.

Comment: I have an idea about the working, but I don't know how to implement it. I need your help., please help me with syntax. Please

Comment: How did you manage to get this far? You must know how to populate the left hand panel, so the right hand panel will be very similar. What GUI API are you using?

Comment: I am using Qt creator 3.0.0 to create GUI. then I transform the UI into Python snippet.

Comment: @ebarr : I know to populate the details on the right hand panel, but the problem is it should depend upon the file which I select in the left hand panel., so how will my program know which file I have selected in the left hand panel. I need help to clear this doubt.

Comment: I use the following code to fetch the name of the file which I select in the left hand side panel 
    "filename = self._ui.listWidget.selectedItems()[0].text()"                        
But it shows the error " list indices out of the range"

Comment: firstly I would print the value of `self._ui.listWidget.selectedItems()` as it is probably returning an empty list.

Comment: "how will my program know which file I have selected in the left hand panel" If you read the documentation for the widget that you use to display that left panel, it should hopefully be obvious. Just read it, start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect a handler to an appropriate signal of the list-widget. Since your list-widget items already contain the filename, the [currentTextChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentTextChanged) seems a good choice:

```
    self._ui.listWidget.currentTextChanged.connect(self.handleFilenameChanged)
    ...

    def handleFilenameChanged(self, filename):
         # get details for filename...
         # load details into output widget...
         # etc...
```